# getInitialProps in never called in NextJS

Tags: graphql, next.js, react-apollo

I have problem with `getInitialProps` method in NextJS. It is never called. This is project where I have `Apollo GraphQL` client for some pages and `getInitialProps` for other. I am not sure how to configure them correctly to work.

`Apollo` is working fine and fetching data as it should. Problem is that `getInitialProps` isn't called.

Here is my custom `_app.js` file

```js
const App = ({ Component, pageProps, apollo }) => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}

const API_URL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php?graphql"
    : "https://page/index.php?graphql"

export default withApollo(({ initialState }) => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: new createHttpLink({
      uri: API_URL,
      fetch: fetch
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })
})(App, { getDataFromTree })
```

And here is how I call `getInitialProps` on page

```js
Coupons.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/data/');
  const data = await res.json();

  console.log(`Data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`);

  return {
    shows: data.map(entry => entry.show)
  };
};
```

Also. Pages where I have `Apollo` fetching data doesn't need to call this `REST API`. `Apollo` pages and `REST` pages are totally different

Comment: can you try `const App = ({ Component, pageProps, apolloClient }) `?

Comment: not gonna work ```ApolloProvider was not passed a client instance. Make sure you pass in your client via the "client" prop.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by following documentation on https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo

Thing is that I wrapped whole `_app` in `Apollo` provider and right way is to wrap only pages that need `Apollo` in it.

Other that need `getInitialProps` should remain as is and call `REST API` in them.